# How to get the count of specific rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in the database shown as shown below:

| Status | Email | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Assigned | admin1@admin1.com | 1 |
| Completed | admin1@admin1.com | 1 |
| InProgress | admin1@admin1.com | 2 |
| Assigned | admin2@admin2.com | 5 |

The possible values in the `Status` column are `Assigned`, `InProgress` and `Completed`.

I want a result to be displayed like this:

| Email | Assigned | InProgress | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| admin1@admin1.com | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| admin2@admin2.com | 5 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Look up conditional aggregation

Comment: thanks @Rajat, conditional aggregation solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select email,
       sum(case when status = 'Assigned' then count else 0 end) as assigned,
       sum(case when status = 'InProgress' then count else 0 end) as InProgress,
       sum(case when status = 'Completed' then count else 0 end) as Completed
from t
group by email;
```